# Looped HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, android-view, horizontalscrollview

I´d like to loop the Views inside a HorizontallScrollView.

Example:

```
HorizontalScrollView holding 5 Views 
When swiping through the Views the behaivior should be like this:
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 1 -> 2 . . . 
Or backwards: 
1 <- 5 <- 4 <- 3 . . .
```

I am looking for a good way to acomplish that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not likely to be practical with a `HorizontalScrollView`. A properly-written `PagerAdapter` -- one that returns a very high value for `getCount()` and returns the same N views -- might be able to pull this off with `ViewPager`. I would not use either of the built-in fragment-based `PagerAdapter` implementations, as those may make some assumptions about the adapter's behavior that your view recycling would violate.

Answer (score 0):

Well even if the question is old it deserves an answer :)

Simple get the scrollViews width or height and get the amount scrolled in x/y.

```
HorizontalScrollView scroller;
int scrollerWidth = scroller.getMeasuredWidth();
int scrollX = scroller.getScrollX();
int activeViewCount = 0;
activeViewCount = (activeViewCount > 0) ? activeViewCount - 1 : 0;
scroller.smoothScrollTo(activeViewCount * scrollerWidth, 0);

if (scrollX >= scrollerWidth) {
   scroller.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

That will make a continous loop.